L1 Best fit line for three dots on a plane
Basically I am tackling a simple question where my goal is to find the best fitting line for three dots on a 2D plane. More specifically, for three dots $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)$ $(x_1 < x_2 < x_3)$, find $a$ and $b$ that minimizes $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3|y_i-(ax_i+b)|$. Since it is just three dots, my goal is to find a solution that just uses elementary math and not any advanced linear algebra. It's quite easy to show geometrically that the best fit line is just the line that passes the two points excluding the middle one(by drawing the cases, we can see that any other line will have a larger distance sum). However, I want to show this just using simple algebra. Finding the minimum for a single-variable function with absolute values is quite easy(just draw a graph) but doing so for multi-variable functions like this one doesn't work out so well. Any suggestions for a good proof?

To get meaningful results you may want to assume that the $x_k$ are distinct. Also, your 'best' line above is not a general answer, unless you are making some assumptions. For example, consider the points $(0,0), (10000,1), (0,2)$.

That's an important assumption I forgot to include. Thank you.

My statement about the best line is incorrect. One of the big advantages of $l_1$ minimisation is that it is insensitive to outliers (albeit with 3 points, none can really be considered an outlier).

There is a straightforward proof using the fact that the cost is convex, but it relies on come facts from convex analysis.

I was wrong again, there is an elementary proof that just relies on properties of $|\cdot|$. See below.

Let $a^*,b^*$ be the values such that $a^*x_k+b^* = y_k$ for $k=1,3$. The cost associated with these values is $|a^*x_2+b^*-y_2|$.
By assumption, we can write $x_2 = t x_1 +(1-t)x_3$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.
Consider $a=a^*+h_a, b=b^*+h_b$.
The cost asociated with $a,b$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_k |ax_k+b-y_k| &=& \sum_k |a^*x_k+b^*-y_k + h_ha_k+h_b| \\
&=& |h_a x_1+h_b| + |a^*x_2+b^*-y_2 + h_a x_2+h_b| + | h_a x_3+h_b| \\
&\ge & |h_a x_1+h_b| + |a^*x_2+b^*-y_2| - | h_a x_2+h_b|+ | h_a x_3+h_b| 
\end{eqnarray}
If we can show that
$| h_a x_2+h_b| \le |h_a x_1+h_b|  + | h_a x_3+h_b|$, then we are finished.
Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
| h_a x_2+h_b| &= & |h_a (t x_1 +(1-t)x_3) +t h_b+(1-t) h_b| \\
&\le & t |h_a x_1+h_b|  + (1-t)| h_a x_3+h_b| \\
&\le& |h_a x_1+h_b|  + | h_a x_3+h_b|
\end{eqnarray}
(A little more work shows that the inequality is strict if $(h_a,h_b) \ne 0$, so in fact, $a^*,b^*$ is the unique solution.)

This is actually exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Just for giggles, here is an answer using convex analysis. Let $f$ be the cost function and note that $f$ is convex, $\lim_{\|(a,b)\| \to \infty} f((a,b)) = \infty$ and so $f$ has a minimiser $(a^*,b^*)$ and we must have $0 \in\partial f((a^*,b^*))$.
If the $(x_k,y_k)$ lie on a line, then it is clear that the corresponding $(a,b)$ is a minimiser, so we will presume that the three points do not lie on a line.
Let $f_k((a,b)) = |ax_k+b-y_k|$, and note that each $f_k$ is convex. It is straightforward to show that the subgradient of $f_k$ is given by
$\partial f_k((a,b))= \begin{cases} \{(x_k,1)\}, & ax_k+b-y_k <0 \\
\{ \{\lambda (x_k,1) | \lambda| \le 1 \}, & ax_k+b-y_k = 0 \\
\{-(x_k,1)\}, & ax_k+b-y_k >0
\end{cases}$.
Theorem 23.8 in Rockafellar's Convex Analysis shows that
$\partial f((a,b)) = \sum_k \partial f_k((a,b))$.
I will call the function $f_k$ active at $(a,b)$ iff $f_k((a,b) = 0$. At most two $f_k$ can be active at $(a^*,b^*)$.
If no $f_k$ is active then $f$ is affine (hence differentiable) and the second component of the derivative is $\pm 1$ and so, at a solution we must have at least one $f_k$ active. If exactly one $f_k$ is active, then an element of $f((a^*,b^*))$ must have the form
$\pm (x_a,1)+ \lambda (x_b,1)+ \pm (x_c,1) = 0$, where $\{a,b,c\} = \{ 1,2,3\}$ and $|\lambda | =1$. Considering the second component, the $\pm$ terms must have opposite signs which we see that two components $f_k$ are active.
If two components are active, then we have
$\lambda_a (x_a,1) + \lambda_b (x_b,1) - (x_c,1) = 0$, with $|\lambda_a| \le 1$, and similarly for $\lambda_b$. Solving for $\lambda_a,\lambda_b$ gives
$(\lambda_a,\lambda_b) = ( { x_c-x_b \over x_a-x_b}, { x_a-x_c \over x_a-x_b}) $, and since $|\lambda_a| \le 1, |\lambda_b| \le 1$, we see that $c=2$ and so both $f_1,f_3$ are active. In particular, this means that the minimiser $(a^*,b^*)$ corresponds to the line passing through $(x_k,y_k)$ for $k=1,3$.
